# Error when passing variables to graphql query/mutation using react-apollo Query & Mutation components

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am trying to implement GraphQL mutation/query in my react application, using 'react-apollo' Mutation/Query component. The queries are working fine on their own and on the server side but I am getting a **POST http://localhost:4000/graphql 400 (Bad Request)** when sending variables via 'react-apollo' Mutation/Query.

Here's the code to my Schema on server side:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export default gql`

    type Edge {
        node: [BusinessDevelopment!] 
    }

    type PageInfo {
        endCursor: String
        hasNextPage: Boolean!
    }

    type BusinessDevelopmentResultCursor {
        edges: Edge!
        pageInfo: PageInfo!
    }

    type BusinessDevelopment {
        id: ID!
        firstName: String!
        lastName: String!
        phone: String!
        email: String
        state: State!
        active: Boolean!
        admin: Boolean!
        regionAdmin: Boolean!
        createdBy: User
        createdOn: Date!
        lastModifiedOn: Date!
        department: String!
    }

    extend type Query {
        allBusinessDevelopment(
            cursor: String
            limit: Int
            byMe: Boolean
        ): BusinessDevelopmentResultCursor
    }
`
```

Here's the code to my Query on client side:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import * as fragments from './../fragments'

export default gql`
    query (
        $cursor: String!,
        $limit: Int!,
        $byMe: Boolean!
    ) {
        allBusinessDevelopment(
            cursor: $cursor,
            limit: $limit,
            byMe: $byMe
        ) {
            edges {
                node {
                    ...Emlpoyee
                }
            },
            pageInfo {
                endCursor,
                hasNextPage
            }
        }
    }
    ${fragments.employee}
`
```

Here's me using the query using 'react-apollo' Query Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

import { getPersonaleAllQuery } from '../../../../../graphql/remoteQueries'

const PersonaleAll = (me) => {
    // ONLY BY admin
    const currentUser = me.me;

    if (currentUser.admin) {
        return (
            <>
                <Query
                    query={getPersonaleAllQuery}
                    variables={{
                        cursor: 'null',
                        limit: 10,
                        byMe: false
                    }}
                >
                    {({loading, error, data}) => {
                        if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
                        if (error) return <div>Error</div>
                        if (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    }}
                </Query>
            </>
        );
    }
    return <h3>Not authorise .!..</h3>
}

export default PersonaleAll;
```

Comment: You can view the response from the server inside the network tab of your browser's developer tools. That will show you what is invalid about the query you are sending. If I had to guess, I'd say it's a typo and your fragment is really named `Employee` not `Emlpoyee`.

Comment: @DanielRearden Thank you so very much! It really was a typo and I was looking for a way to view the response from the server side too! Your answer was really helpful.